# Is it possible to stream a YouTube video in Powerpoint for Mac 2011?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I would like to have a video in a Powerpoint presentation, without having to download the file.
So just insert a link to youtube or vimeo, and then being able to play it directly form the presentation.
Is this possible at all?

Edit: I did mean "stream" a YouTube video

Comment: Yes, but you will have to be on internet to do it. If the video changes its name or location you r in trouble.

Comment: Just to clarify...Embedding means you have it downloaded to your computer, what you asking for is called "Streaming".

Comment: Yes it is possible, by using Hyperlink. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple method by using the **Hyperlink** command in PowerPoint.

You can Hyperlink any object in you Presentation.

Here is a sample how to do it for this sample presentation I made.

[image]

Now Right Click on the Text Box "Streaming You Tube" and select Hyperlink.

In Hyperlink paste the link to the you tube video.

It looks like this in my example.
[image]

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for. I would prefer not to switch applications, but have it playing back in the presentation.

Comment: @Nicolai To my knowledge you can not embed YouTube player in to PowerPoint. PowerPoint it self can not play any movies at all, it uses external resources to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, presuming the desire to embed and not stream, I use a little utility called Videobox, by Tasty Apps, to extract the video file from Vimeo or YouTube, and then I embed it directly into PowerPoint.

See the following Lynda.com clip: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZUh2ErM_Ls

Comment: Without Download !

Comment: Which is why I added the caveat "presuming the desire to embed and not stream". The method that PPT uses for accomplishing this under Windows is to embed a Shockwave object from the Developer menu, and embed the YouTube link through that. If there's an equivalent method of doing so in PPT 2011 for Mac, I've not seen it.

Comment: The question is specific to Streaming, and not to Embedding.